# Clarification of sugared versus unsugared ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

In the Swift 3 Migration Guide (https://swift.org/migration-guide/) Apple says:

*Unsugared use of the ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type will have to be replaced with the postfix ! notation.*

Could some one clarify what a "sugared" use of ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional would look like?

Comment: That quote is found in the Swift proposal but without further clarification: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md